# Adding new library to jsbin

Tags: javascript, jsbin

Trying to add Tangle.js as a new library on browser console. Can anyone tell us where I'm going wrong?

```
var mylib = {
text: 'Tangle',
scripts: [
{ text: 'Tangle.js', url: 'http://worrydream.com/Tangle/Tangle.js' }
]
}; // the "My Library" object above
libraries.add(mylib);
```

Comment: TBH this seems fine to me and should work - unless you're calling libraries.clear()

What browser are you using? as some older ones don't support the Storage API

To confirm - are you running this in the browser's console or JS Bin's console?

Comment: Hi Visualife - we're running this in Chrome browser console. The error we're getting is: Error: libraries is not defined(…)